# Variable frequency pulse train generation

Tags: digital-logic, 555, square

I wanted to create a pulse train of such a kind that the first pulse is high for a time=4x, then the next pulse is on for x, and the next for 4x... and so on. (without using microcontrollers/programmable devices)

[image]

- From reading a couple of questions on the SE I think we can use two
  555 timers (or a 556) to achieve a variable frequency , although I'm
  not exactly certain on how that works.
- A second approach can be to use two 555s in astable mode, and keep
  switching between them. I think we can use a 2x1 multiplexer , but I'm
  confused regarding what exactly should be fed to the select line...

How exactly can I create a pulse train of such a kind?

Comment: Would you consider using a microcontroller? That is what I would do.

Comment: The project I am working on doesn't allow the use of microcontrollers unfortunately.

Comment: fill in the low intervals ... then use an appropriately sized counter with some decoding logic ... that is not a square wave ... it is a pulse train

Comment: Can you use a small CPLD? That'd be cheap and flexible. More importantly: please edit your question and rewrite the beginning, adding all the missing information about what circuit or equipment this is all for and why it's needed. Otherwise it's impossible to assess and we end up with you yes/no+ing each suggestion one by one in a big comment chain. (Don't dump two lines in starting with "Edit:" - rewrite the single text.)

Comment: No, unfortunately we cant use anything programmable. Also, what exactly should I edit in my question?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly otherwise I'd be writing it for you. I've summarised in my comment what's needed. Refer to other, well-voted and detailed questions on the site as examples, if you need to. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: I've mentioned the question, explained it, explained 2 possible approaches and then summarised the question again. Not sure what more I can do

Comment: Your definition of a good question isn't the other site users' definition, then. I've attempted to help but you're not helping yourself and it's your responsibility, not mine.  I'll leave it to the Close votes.

Comment: @satan29 I cannot tell how long the lows (gaps) between the highs are. So you haven't done everything you could do. (I also don't know for sure that it must start with 4 and cannot begin any other way. You mention the one case. But you do not exclude other possibilities for starting up. One could guess. But again, this should be made explicit and clearer. Less of an issue. But still... there's always more you can do to clarify a question.)

Comment: @jonk thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Is it allowed to use a digital solution? This could be implemented as a simple state machine that is hard-wired. Is it for a digital logic class or analog or?

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is only a few states long (e.g. 11110010) , you can use a counter and a mux, where the eight inputs to the mux are your states in sequence.